# getElementById not working within if statement - Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JS script to swap out elements containing Flash and replace them with other formats for users who don't have Flash installed.

```
var hideclass="hidden"
var showclass="empty"


function flashFixMain(){    
if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("7.0.0")) {

    document.getElementById('logoflash').className=showclass;
    document.getElementById('logononflash').className=hideclass;

} else {

    document.getElementById('logoflash').className=hideclass;
    document.getElementById('logononflash').className=showclass;

    }
}
```

And put simply, it doesn't work.

- The if statement works fine - putting an alert in the appropriate place pops up fine.
- I've checked the source of the appropriate page(s) online, and the element name pops up exactly as written (and only once!).
- The class names work fine, as they are used as defaults on the page at the start.

So does anyone have any ideas what I might have missed?

Comment: can you give more details like your html and css class definitions.
try using $("p").addClass("myClass yourClass"); and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Did you get any farther? Did you see if overwriting existing class was an issue? (see my answer that talks about that).

Comment: Overwriting classes wasn't an issue - I tend to use extra DIV tags for things like this.

What I have worked out is that the code works perfectly if called by a button - it seems to be an issue with the fact that it's called on window.onload

Comment: Finally sorted - a mate suggested that I should use jquery ready, as the elements didn't exist when I was trying to change them!

Answer (score 8):

change

```
document.getElementById('logoflash').class=showclass;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('logoflash').className = showclass;
```

it's `className`, not `class`

Comment: I can't believe I missed this - but having changed it over to the correct format, it's still not working so I think there's something else wrong too.

Comment: @MattBowyer - It does seem to work in [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxjdv/), other than that, it's not easy to test this ?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `.class` you need to use the [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) property; for instance:

```
document.getElementById('logoflash').className = showclass;
```

In modern browsers you can also use [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) to add a class rather than replace all existing classes:

```
document.getElementById('logoflash').classList.add(showclass);
```

As an aside, you could consider moving a few statements around like this:

```
var hasFlash = swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("7.0.0"),
logoFlash = document.getElementById('logoflash'),
logoNonFlash = document.getElementById('logononflash');

logoFlash.className = hasFlash ? showclass : hideclass;
logoNonFlash.className = hasFlash ? hideclass : showclass;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a quick test scenario and without seeing more of your environment, do not see anything that should keep this from working as expected.

The one thing I did notice while doing a write up w/o using jQuery (which I guess you are NOT using?) is that your 'addClass' is really a 'REPLACE' class value. You are simply setting it to a single class.

This makes me think, not having seen your environment, that some OTHER classes might be already assigned to your elements that are getting wiped out. This could be causing unexpected behaviour if some of your display is dependent on these other classes...

Without seeing more of your scenario, that is the only thing that seems like it might be an issue.

Anyway, here is my test setup. You might find something in this useful.

```
<div id="logoflash" class='something'>
    Logoflash
</div>

<div id="logononflash" class='else' >
    logononflash
</div>



<script>

var swfobject = {FlashPlayerVersion: '7.0.1', hasFlashPlayerVersion: function(v) {if(v == this.FlashPlayerVersion) return true; else return false;}, myName: 'fakeSWObject' };
console.log(swfobject)

var hideclass = "hidden"
var showclass = "empty"
var getById = function(sID) { return document.getElementById(sID); };
var addClass = function(sID, sClass) { getById(sID).className += ' ' + sClass  };

function toggleEl(sID, bState){
    console.log('begin toggleEl')
    console.log('bState: ' + bState)
    try {
        if(bState == undefined) {
            console.log('Toggling by element state');
            getById(sID).style.display = getById(sID).style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
        } else {
            console.log('Toggling by argument');
            getById(sID).style.display = !!bState ? 'block' : 'none';
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

function flashFixMain(){

  if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("7.0.0")) {
    console.log('Is Flash 7.0.0');
    toggleEl('logoflash', true);
    toggleEl('logononflash', false);
    addClass('logoflash', hideclass);
    addClass('logononflash', showclass);

} else {
    console.log('Is NOT Flash 7.0.0');
    toggleEl('logoflash', true)
    toggleEl('logononflash', false)
    addClass('logoflash', showclass);
    addClass('logononflash', hideclass);
    }
}


$(function(){ // Yes, this is jQuery to fire after doc is ready
    flashFixMain();
})

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

use Jquery:

```
$("#logoflash").addClass(hideclass);
```

or

```
$('#logoflash').toggleClass(hideclass, swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("7.0.0"));
```

Comment: The question isn't tagged with jQuery.

Comment: i din't look at that. i am sorry.

Comment: No worries, it happens :)